# Python pipenv fails to install libraries?

Tags: python, django, ssl, pipenv, pipenv-install

My pipenv environment refuses to install various python libraries, citing a problem with the ssl certificate, any solutions out there?
Here is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\NAME\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\mainsite> pipenv install django
Installing django...
Error:  An error occurred while installing django!
Error text: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django

Installation Failed
```

Comment: I don't see any errors related to ssl certificates. The only error I see is "the ssl module in Python is not available", which is an entirely different problem. How did you install Python?

Comment: I just downloaded python off of the python page and added it to my path.